# How to hide code when I run program in console in R studio?

Tags: r

I use R studio. when I run my script I see in console the outputs together with the code.
I dont want the console will print also the code. How I can hide it?

[image]

Comment: If you want to use the output only have a look at https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/ - this enables you to standartise your reports and share them as HTML and PDF easily

Comment: TY. I know markdown, but I prefer not to use it. there is no any possible solution?

Comment: You can't, at least not completely.  The closest I think you can come would be to save your code and `source()` it.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento since we're using RStudio, this can be done via the rstudio api without having to save the file - see below

Comment: That's neat Allan (+1) and I'm not surprised that you found something helpful using the `rstudioapi`  but the point I was attempting to make is that it's not possible with zero console input, after all, at least one command has to be executed.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento thanks. I wondered if it would be possible to have `run()` executed silently via an RStudio keyboard binding, say using the `shrtcts` add-in package, but this just replaces `run` with `shrtcts:::shortcut_01()` (though can be done with an easy keybinding), so it seems you are right that there will always be at least one function call printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do this, which is to source selected text from inside the RStudio document pane. You can do this via the Rstudio API. First define the following function:

```r
run <- function() {
  eval(parse(text = rstudioapi::primary_selection(
  rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext())$text))
}
```

Now in your RStudio, you can select text in your document pane like this:

[image]

And in the R console, you can do:

```r
run()
#> [1] "I only want to see this message"
```

And you can see the variables have changed as expected:

```r
x
#> [1] 10
```

If you wanted to, you could bind this function to a keyboard shortcut in R Studio.